# How to show two items in a single row from an array of items in html?

Tags: html, css

I've a list of items and in `webView` I'm showing 4 elements in each row. But in `mobileView` i want to show 2 elements in a single row. This is my `html` file.

```
<div class="row my-3 cust-heading" style="margin-left: 39vh; margin-right: 39vh;">
    <div class="col-md-3 my-4 products" ng-repeat="product in productList track by $index" ng-if="$index<12">
        <div class="productList">
            <img class="product-image mb-2" src="{{product.imageLink}}" />
            <h6 class="product-name" style="font-size: 14px;">
                <b>{{product.productName}}</b>
            </h6>
            <small style="font-size: 11px; text-transform: uppercase;" ng-if="product.amountFlag==1"><strike>{{product.currencyCode}} {{product.commaSeparatedPrice}}</strike>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;-{{product.discountAmount}}</small>
            <small style="font-size: 11px; text-transform: uppercase;" ng-if="product.amountFlag==0 && product.percentFlag==1"><strike>{{product.currencyCode}} {{product.commaSeparatedPrice}}</strike>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;-{{product.discountPercent}}%</small>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                <small style="font-size: 11px; text-transform: uppercase;color:coral" ng-if="product.amountFlag==1">{{product.currencyCode}} {{product.commaSeparatedFinalPrice}}</small>
                <small style="font-size: 11px; text-transform: uppercase;color:coral" ng-if="product.amountFlag==0 && product.percentFlag==1">{{product.currencyCode}} {{product.commaSeparatedFinalPrice}}</small>
                <small style="font-size: 11px; text-transform: uppercase;color:coral" ng-if="product.amountFlag==0 && product.percentFlag==0">{{product.currencyCode}} {{product.commaSeparatedPrice}}</small>
                <small style="font-size: 11px;"><a href="{{product.messengerLink}}"><i class="fab fa-facebook-messenger"></i> Buy</a></small>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my `css` media query:

```
@media (max-width: 425px) {
    .header-img {
        background-image: url('/img/bg-mobile-new.jpeg') !important;
    }
    .cus-button {
        text-align: center!important;
    }
    .cus-heading {
        padding-left: 15px!important;
    }

    .container {
        text-align: center
    }


  }
```

This is the `webView`:

[image]

This is how it looks like in mobile:

[image]

What do I need to do to show 2 items in one `row` in mobileView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="col-md-3 ...etc
```

Sets the width (at medium res.) to 3 out of 12 columns = 4

You can default it to 2 columns at lower resolutions bij doing this:

```
<div class="col-6 col-md-3 ...etc
```

maybe change productlist to product, since the loop is around the 'list' now

Also: remove on the row:

```
margin-left: 39vh; margin-right: 39vh;
```

if you want to center the page use a

```
<div class="container">...</div>
```

around the row

check:[grid system bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)

Comment: changed the class to this : class="col-6 col-md-3 my-4 products" but in mobile view, lists are still showing in one line

Comment: please check with F12 if the rows/cols are in order and you can try a lower number , like col-4 to see if its a padding problem... if 2 cols wont fit because of content, you would see the same

Comment: ow sorry :  margin-left: 39vh; margin-right: 39vh;  remove those ! on the row

Comment: yes that solved the problem, but can't remove that. I had to create another similar div and add flag variable in angular to decide which one to show when. cause for webView, that was needed and media query was not working due to some reason.